# Pam.exec exit code 8

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pam

I'm trying to use pam.d to execute a script on user login. Right now I'm editing the /etc/pam.d/su file. Every time I log in to a user I get "Exit code 8".

The command I put in there is:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /etc/calendar/test
```

The path /etc/calendar/test is the path to the test script I have written. The script looks like this.

```
echo hi
```

I'm using this basic script just to test. Eventually I will implement a script that logs the user that logged in and what time. That code will look like:

```
user=$(whoami)
date=$(date)
echo $user logged in at $date >> /etc/calendar/tripwire_file
```

Any insight provided on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the script running & echoing "hi" somewhere, and where? Where you you see the "Exit code 8" message?

Comment: I see the exit code message when I log into users. So the pam_exec.so module is working to an extent, but it's having an error in execution.

Comment: Have the same issue, have you managed solve it?